# Is there any alternative way to use qt4 in travis CI for osx (brew removed qt4)

Tags: macos, qt4, homebrew, travis-ci

I was using `brew install qt` for using qt4 lib in travis CI on a osx image with (el capitan).

But they removed the qt4 package from brew and the travis build is failing.

Is there any other way to install qt4 lib in travis?

Comment: There's an unofficial tap for qt4. https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4

Comment: @equal_l2 I tried it before but it's not working on el capitan ... it get timeout on travis at make step of qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run:

```
brew tap cartr/qt4
brew tap-pin cartr/qt4
brew install cartr/qt4/qt
brew install cartr/qt4/pyqt
```

Make sure to prepend your build command with `travis_wait 30`, since TravisCI will time-out your build if it runs for ten minutes without any output.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution ...
i tried 

`brew tap freeCAD/freecad
brew install freecad/freecad/qt`

and also the [cartr/homebrew-qt4](http://%20github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4) works well right now the problem with older os fixed ([Provide bottles for older OS versions](https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4/issues/8))